# Procedure com CASE na cláusula WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure, case

Bom minha duvida é a seguinte, sou iniciante no sql serve,
eu estou executando uma procedure e nela usando o método CASE

o código a seguir mostra o que eu estou fazendo:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[STP_S_Cliente_Busca](
    @Busca varchar(255),
    @Opao varchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT
    * 
FROM
    tb_cliente 
WHERE
CASE 
    WHEN @Opao = 'NOME' THEN Nome LIKE '%'+ @Busca +'%' 
        WHEN @Opao = 'STATUS' THEN Status_Cliente LIKE '%'+@Busca+'%'
        WHEN @Opao = 'CNPJ' THEN CNPJ LIKE '%'+@Busca+'%'
        WHEN @Opao = 'EMAIL' THEN Email LIKE '%'+@Busca+'%'
        WHEN @Opao = 'TELEFONE' THEN Whatsapp LIKE '%'+@Busca+'%'
END
ORDER BY
    Nome DESC
END
```

Porém por algum motivo não executa, eu já fiz dessa maneira em mysql e funcionou normalmente, acredito que em sql server tenha algum detalhe diferente, mas pelo que vi em pesquisas feita na internet o case parece certo.
Estou executando a regra corretamente? Ou esta realmente errado?

Quero realmente entender o que esta de errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jéssica, pelo que sei não é possível colocar uma condição dentro do Case no SQL Server, acredito que seja possível apenas retornar um valor.
Para o caso que você postou, sugiro a versão abaixo, onde o Case é utilizado para retornar o valor de uma das colunas, e o valor retornado é utilizado na condição:

```
WHERE
  CASE 
    WHEN @Opao = 'NOME' THEN Nome 
    WHEN @Opao = 'STATUS' THEN Status_Cliente 
    WHEN @Opao = 'CNPJ' THEN CNPJ
    WHEN @Opao = 'EMAIL' THEN Email
    WHEN @Opao = 'TELEFONE' THEN Whatsapp
  END LIKE '%' + @Busca + '%'
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Testei dessa forma, parece funcionar quando os valores são int por exemplo o status, porem quando tentei fazer uma busca por Nome me retornou um erro inesperado, onde diz: Falha ao converter o varchar valor 'TESTE 1' para o tipo de dados int. tentei colocar um CONVERT VARCHAR mais o erro persiste

Comment: Gostei de sua solução, Sílvio.

Comment: Jéssica, acho que converter para varchar depois do Then deveria resolver, mas se for assim acho que seria melhor partir para algo como o José Diz sugeriu, ou talvez utilizar Cases separados para colunas int e varchar.

Comment: Valeu José Diz.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que os implementadores do MySQL ofereceram algo a mais para os desenvolvedores.

No SQL Server há algumas formas de obter o que deseja. Por exemplo:

```
-- código #1
SELECT ...
  from ...
  where (@Opcao = 'NOME' and Nome like '%'+@Busca+'%')
      or (@Opcao = 'STATUS' and Status_Cliente like '%'+@Busca+'%')
      or (@Opcao = 'CNPJ' and CNPJ like '%'+@Busca+'%')
      or (@Opcao = 'EMAIL' and Email like '%'+@Busca+'%')
      or (@Opcao = 'TELEFONE' and Whatsapp like '%'+@Busca+'%')
  order by NOME desc;
```

Outra abordagem, com o uso de CASE, é a seguinte:

```
-- código #2
SELECT ...
  from ...
  where case when @Opcao = 'NOME'
                  then case when Nome like '%'+@Busca+'%'
                                 then 1
                            else 0 end
             when @Opcao = 'STATUS'
                  then case when Status_Cliente like '%'+@Busca+'%'
                                 then 1
                            else 0 end
             when @Opcao = 'CNPJ'
                  then case when CNPJ like '%'+@Busca+'%'
                                 then 1
                            else 0 end
             when @Opcao = 'EMAIL'
                  then case when Email like '%'+@Busca+'%'
                                 then 1
                            else 0 end
             when @Opcao = 'TELEFONE'
                  then case when Whatsapp like '%'+@Busca+'%'
                                 then 1
                            else 0 end
             else 0 end = 1
  order by NOME desc;
```

Escreve-se mais mas é mais eficiente do que o código #1 pois somente avalia a expressão com LIKE quando necessário.